# Java: Casting rule for hierarchy inheritance

Tags: java, casting

As picture shown, I have an hierarchy of inherited classes. I am looking for a general rule as `up to down` or `down to up` rules.

I mean, **Which one i am permitted to Cast? And Why?**

```
Child ch;
Parent p=(Parent ) ch;
```

OR

```
Parent p;
Child  ch=(Child  ) p;
```

[image]

Comment: both, but you can't be sure that a parent is a child

Comment: it depends is parent a child or is child a parent?

Comment: Both but do `instanceof` before you cast `Parent` -> `Child`

Comment: As you can see, there's are a lot of people who don't understand this.

Comment: Most of us thought there was an instanciation on the variable. But not. You see misunderstanding where there is only inattention.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can always implicitly cast a reference of type `Child` to a reference of type `Parent`. You can explicitly cast a reference of type `Parent` to a reference of type `Child`, but this may fail at run time with a `ClassCastException` if the object referenced is not in fact a `Child`.

It may be helpful to illustrate *why* this is the case, though.

What does it really mean to have a reference of type `Parent`? It basically means that you can use any of the methods that `Parent` defines (I'm doing a bit of glossing over here, especially with respect to fields and `null`s). If `Child extends Parent`, then it inherits all of those methods. So, it's always safe to treat an object of type `Child` as if it were an object of type `Parent`, since any method that you'd want to use from that `Parent` reference must exist on the `Child` object, too.

```
Child c = getSomeObject();
Parent p = c;
p.doSomethingParental();
```

Even though the reference `p` points to a `Child` object, that `Child` inherits the `doSomethingParental` method, so this code works fine.

How about the other way around? Well, let's say that `Child extends Parent` and adds a method `beAGoodChild()`. Now you have a `Parent` reference, and you want to cast it to `Child`:

```
Parent p = getSomeOtherObject();
Child c = (Child) p;
c.beAGoodChild();
```

Obviously, that last line can only work if `c` really is a `Child` (and not just a plain ol' `Parent`). If it's not, then the reasonable place to catch that mistake is in the second line, where we do the casting. That makes it easier to spot bugs quicker; rather than spotting them when we try to use a method they don't have (which could happen long after the casting happened), it's nicer if we catch them at the cast time, and then have a guarantee that any call to `c.beAGoodChild()` will always succeed. Basically, it lets you ignore the question of "is this really a Child?" except at certain specific instances (namely, when casting).

Answer (score 1):

You are permitted to *code* either cast.  The first case does not even need to have the cast in order to be accepted by the compiler.

At execution time, though, the variable `p` in the second case must actually reference an instance of `Child` (or some subclass of `Child`) or a cast check exception will be raised.

Remember, *cast does not actually change the type of the object*, it merely asserts/verifies that the object is permitted to be treated as the specified type.

Comment: Second case is not right since it's instanciated as a Parent. You can not specialized in the other way after the instanciation. You do not answer to the question.

Comment: @lpratlong - There is no indication as to how `p` got set in the second case.  It could easily have been set by the statement `Parent p = new Child();`

Comment: Oooooops, you're true Oo. I suspect an edition on the Question. :)

Answer (score -1):

**EDIT**

As I am like a blind man sometimes, I did not see that you did not initialize your variables.
So, here is an explanation considering this initialization:

*case 1*

```
Child ch = new Child();
Parent p=(Parent ) ch;
```

*case 2*

```
Parent p = new Parent();
Child  ch=(Child  ) p;
```

**END EDIT**

You can cast `Child` as a `Parent` since `Child` is also a `Parent` thanks to inheritance.

You can not cast `Parent` as a `Child` since `Parent` is instanciate as a `Parent` and so is NOT a `Child`.

**I take an example:**

I have a pen. This is also a tool used to write.

But if I take a standard tool (let's say it has a handle and a function), I can not consider it as a pen, because it can't write.

**Let's go further**

Now, I have a bi-color pen!!! So great, I love that!

It's a Pen and it's a Tool, so I can consider it as a Bicolor-Pen, as a Pen and as a Tool!

If I take a normal Pen, it does not have bi-color! It's just a Pen and also a Tool.

**And a code example**

```
public class Human {
    protected String chromosome;

    private int legs, arms = 2;
    private int head = 1;

}

public class Man extends Human {

     private boolean drinkBeer = true;       

     public Man() {
        chromosome = "XY";
     }
}

public class Woman extends Human {
    private boolean loveHandbags = true;

    public Woman() {
        chromosome = "XX";
    }

}
```

A Man is also an human since he has 2 legs, 2 arms and 1 head. A woman too.
But, if I have an human and I don't know his specialized kind, I can not say what is its determinating chromosome (or if he loves beers or handbags).

I hope my explanation has help you to understand and I apologize to the ladies :).

**Edit**

I am not speaking about the fact that it compiles or not (it will compile). But you will have a `ClassCastException` at the runtime: https://ideone.com/kolTwa

Comment: A `Parent` object could be a `Child` object, casted.

Comment: @Unihedron Not quite, but close. A `Parent` object is, by definition, not a `Child` object. But a _reference_ of type `Parent` can also reference an object of type `Child`. The distinction between reference and object is important, especially for this question.

Comment: @Unihedron I have added some precision on parent instanciation. Thanks for the remark.

Comment: Well, I've been working with Java for 15 years, much of it inside the a JVM.  (Actually coded the support for the checkcast bytecode.)  So I suspect that your assessment is wrong.

Comment: Just one note, in your code you have public Man() as the constructor for the Woman class

Comment: @HotLicks Okay now I'm also confused

Comment: @RobinHellemans It's fixed! Copy / paste error. Hot Licks, I have been working with Java for a long time too. I do not say we can not cast a Parent as a Child, I say that, in the example provided in the question, it will not be possible. It will result to a ClassCastException. So, speeking about concept, it's not possible. Here is the demo: https://ideone.com/kolTwa

Comment: @HotLicks See my comment below. I did not see the non-initialization :). I edited my answer to take this. My explanation is valid only for some initialization of variables.

Answer (score -1):

Yes one can cast Child as  Parent, so following will work

```
Child ch = new Child();
Parent p=(Parent) ch;  
System.out.println("Working!!");
```

While this will not work:

```
Parent p= new Parent();
Child ch = (Parent)p;  
System.out.println("won't work!!");
```

//get incompatible types error.

Mind it in your code you havn't initialized any object that is never used new operator so you will get 'p/ch never initialized error'.

Comment: But `Parent p= new Child(); Child ch = (Parent)p;` *will* work, and that is the most important scenario to understand.

Comment: Hey! check it once again it is not working 'error: incompatible types' http://ideone.com/aXVBqF

Comment: Yes, and, as I said, that is the most important scenario to understand when dealing with cast.

Comment: Yes Parent p= new Child(); Child ch = (Parent)p; will not work.why?
What Parent p= new Child(); will do is create an instance of Child(as new Child(); is on RHS) which is referenced by Parent(as Parent is on LHS); so we have an instance of Child referenced by p which is of Parent type, which is valid.
Now as the instance is of child type it can be cast to Parent by doing (Parent)p; but since we have casted it to Parent we cannot refer it using a Child type reference, we can refer it only through Parent type reference.So
Child ch = (Parent)p;
//"Won't work"
Parent p1 = (Parent)p;//Work

Comment: Code it up and try it.  What matters in the cast is what kind of object you ACTUALLY have, and casting an object reference back and forth does not change the type of the ACTUAL object itself.

Answer (score -2):

There are two type of casting up and down but Java allow only "UPCASTING" you can also "DOWNCAST" in JAVA but it can throw run time exception. It will throw a run time exception in your case as  well.

"UPCASTING": It means That when you have child class you can Casting it to Parent Class, so this is legal casting.

"DownCasting" It means That You want casting a Parent class  to Child class. It is Dangerous in Java. If object can be cast to target type then it works otherwise it throws an run time exception .

In case of DOWNCASTING  Program  can throw a Runtime Exception (a java.lang.ClassCastException).

Why Casting a Parent to Child is Dangerous :-

When we use (cast)OBJ1 it try to cast that obj1 to target type. For example

```
Child c = (Child)p1.
```

It will try to cast p1 to Child type. p1 can either have child class reference or Parent class reference..

```
p1 = new Parent() // It would not work and throw an exception (java.lang.ClassCastException) see explanation below
```

OR

```
p1 = new Child()   // It will work.
```

Here is a simple reason Casting an object to some specific type allow us to treat it as object of that type. So if we cast child to parent then we can treat it as a object of parent and can call any parent method.  However the call of method goes to the actual type in this case function of child class will be executed while we already cast object to Parent.

Child class will have all the methods and instance variable available which are defined in Parent class. So if you cast a child object to parent class and call any method of parent class it will work perfectly(However it will call child class method).

In other case there would be some additional methods/instance variables defined in child class. So when you cast parent object to child class and try to call such a method (extra method defined in child class) it would not find in parent object and create problem.

Comment: If upcasting is always allowed and doesn't need the `(cast)` operation, and downcasting is always an error, what is `(cast)` used for???

Comment: Yes. In case of casting cast keyword is not allowed as it is safe and compiler allowed it. Cast keyword is required in case of downcasting otherwise compiler generate error.

Comment: But you say above that downcasting is always an error.  So why bother with the cast op at all?

Comment: If instanciation is on the Child, so you can downcast a parent variable. If `Parent p = new Child()`, you can do `(Child) p`. So your answer is wrong. Downcasting is not illegal. When you cast a variable, you cast its type, so its visibility, not what is assigned to it.

Comment: Yes. As given in problem downcasting .... Casting Parent to Child will always an error.  On other hand there are some possibility that the parent object you are casting to child object have reference of some other child object in that case it will work.

Comment: @lpratlong I completely agree with you that DOWNCASTING is not always illegal and it always depends on the object to which you are casting if that object can be cast  to destination type it works otherwise it will throw an exception. I said down casting is illegal in current questions context.